# How to use OpenID between Drupal and .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drupal-8

I want to integration OpenID authentication between Drupal and MVC where MVC will be Identity Provider and Drupal is Service Provider. kindly help me How is it posible

Comment: It will be SSO with OpenID

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the module offered by miniOrange - [Drupal Oauth](https://plugins.miniorange.com/drupal-sso-oauth-openid-single-sign-on)
the functionality you are looking for is listed in their feature list - available with Premium or higher tier plans.